# jQuery syntax for radio button

Tags: jquery

In an attempt to abbreviate code and perhaps make it run a touch faster, I tried this code for getting the value if an input whose name is `key` is a radio button:

```
var elem = $(':input[name^="'+key+'"]');
currVal = (elem.prop('type') == 'radio' ? 
  ':input[name^="'+key+'"]:checked').val() : elem.val());
```

I've tried various ways to abbreviate the instruction

```
':input[name^="'+key+'"]:checked')
```

but nothing works.

Is there a way of using `elem` in this situation?

Comment: What exactly is the desired result?  You are selecting `things` to get `what`?

Comment: Not sure having a leading `:` is correct. That's normally used for pseudo attributes. Try removing it

Comment: @freefaller `:input` will match multiple things, such as `input`, `select`, `textarea`

Comment: @Taplar everyday's a school day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you already have the element with

```
var elem = $(':input[name^="'+key+'"]');
```

So instead of looking up all the elements again, use filter

```
elem.filter(":checked").val()
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `$("input[name='+key+'][type='radio']:checked").val();` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/wvbxmgpe/

```
var elem = $(':input[name^="'+key+'"]'),
currVal = elem.prop('type') == 'radio'
  ? $(':input[name^="'+key+'"]:checked').val()
  : elem.val();
```